# Can't access input field using jquery click function

Tags: jquery, symfony, jquery-steps, formvalidation.io

I use Symfony to generate a form in witch  i use jquery stepy and bootstrap formvalidtion. i want to handle jquery click function for some field of my form but it seems that nothing is happening.
this is the jquery call :

```
$( "#myFieldId" ).click(function() {
            alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
        });
```

I checked that the field id exists once in the form.
Please some help.

Comment: Help? You should provide a reproducible demo. I guess you are just trying to bind the click event before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: the problem is when i add an inut field i can access the field. Secand i have tried $( "#myFieldId" ).on( "click", function() {
            alert( $( this ).text() );
        }); with no change

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the click event was blocked by the formvalidation api. I've tried

```
    $('#fos_user_registration_form_ncin').unbind('click').click(function(){
alert("hello");
});
```

and this work for me.
Thank you nicael.